# I'm calling a services API, and it returns a response object, how can I inspect all its properties etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm calling a services API, and it returns a response object, how can I inspect all its properties etc?

I don't know the exact nature of the response object, and there is little documentation on it.

```
response = .....
```

In irb, I just do a `puts response`, will this display all the properties or they can still be hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `response.inspect`